# Как перевести десятичное число в двоичное на python?

Tags: python

Хочу написать алгоритм по переводу числа из десятичной сс в двоичную, но столкнулся с проблемой - код ниже заходит в бесконечный цикл. Если помните, нужно делить число на 2. Весь алгоритм писать не нужно, опишите проблему и её решение кода ниже

```
a = int(input())

x = []
integer = []
result = []

x = list(str(a))[::-1]


while True:
    if a != 1 and a != 0:
        if a % 2 == 0:
            result.append(0)
            a = a / 2
        elif a % 2 == 1:
            result.append(1)
            a = a / 2
    else:
        False
```

Comment: Код с `else: False` ничего не делает. Если вы хотели выйти из цикла нужно вызывать `break`. А так, для получения числа в двоичной форме можно использовать встроенную функцию `bin`

Comment: `print(bin(a))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

вы просто написали много ненужного кода

```
a = int(input())
result = []

while a:
    result.append(a % 2)
    a //= 2
result.reverse()
print(result)
```

Answer (score 2):

> код ниже заходит в бесконечный цикл

```
else:
    False
```

Данный код не завершает цикл, а просто вызывает значение False. Чтобы завершить цикл нужно либо использовать оператор break, либо в условии использовать переменную и заменить её значение на False для прекращения работы цикла.

*1 способ завершения цикла*
**

```
a = True
while a:  # пока a is True 
    if False:
        pass
    else:
        a = False
```

*2 способ*

```
While True:
    If False:
        pass  # пропустить
    else:
        break  # завершение цикла
```

Также a = a / 2 будет возвращать дробное значение и условие a == 1 или a == 0 никогда не выполнится.

Вот работающий код:

```
a = int(input())
    
x = []
integer = []
result = []
    
x = list(str(a))[::-1]
    
    
while True:
    if a != 0:
        if a % 2 == 0:
            result.append(0)
            a = a // 2
        elif a % 2:
             result.append(1)
             a = a // 2
    else:
        result.reverse()
        print(result)
        break
```